# How to run each tests on multiple mobile device in parallel using TestNG, Java and Appium?

Tags: java, testng, appium

I have 5 mobile devices and I want to run my automated mobile app tests cases on all the devices for checking the compatibility. For this, I need to run each test on all 5 devices simultaneously. So if I have 10 test cases, each will run on all devices which will make the total count 50.

I am creating a device pool dynamically. The pool will have devices that are connected to the host machine. So it will not have any prior idea of device UDID before running test cases. I understand that multiple Appium sessions are to be created for this. The problem is that I need to somehow create multiple copies of each test case depending on the number of devices connected and then run each of them on all the devices.

Example:

```
@Test
public void test1(){
}
@Test
public void test2(){
}
```

The device pool has 5 devices connected. Now I want test1() to be run on each device. Similarly, it applies to test2(). I can create multiple Appium session and assign a device from the device pool. The problem is how to duplicate test methods on the runtime in TestNG.

I couldn't find any straightforward way of doing this in TestNG. Is it possible to achieve? If yes, any example would work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate multiple appium session for each device.
Also, follow the following link to proceed with things in details.

https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-parallel-execution-using-testng/

Comment: I am dynamically creating a device pool and I want to assign devices from the pool to test cases. The above link you gave only works when you already know the device UDID prior to running the test cases.

Comment: Which device pool are you using? Prior to running I assume you have all the information regarding the devices present in your device pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven and TestNG - then you should know about .xml files with suite of tests. Try to implement [IAlterSuiteListener](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.11enter) and alter your .xml with tests file.
[Test NG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) allows separating threads in various ways:
for example for 3 devices you can run 1 same test in such way:

1. Create TestNG .xml file with tests
2. Specify in this xml - listener that implements IAlterSuiteListener
3. Alter xml file in runtime with listener, that can detect number of connected devices (that equals thread number), so you can set `thread-count` and add Tests in loop.

```
suite name="Android Compatibility Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="3"

<test name="Android Compatibility Test-1">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.android_tests.AndroidCompatibilityTest">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

  <test name="Android Compatibility Test-2">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.android_tests.AndroidCompatibilityTest">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

 <test name="Android Compatibility Test-3">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.android_tests.AndroidCompatibilityTest">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Read an [documentation](https://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/parallel-tests/) about parallelism in Appium
[1](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.11enter): https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.11enter code here/org/testng/IAlterSuiteListener.html